# Утилита для импорта данных в БД

Tags: база-данных, big-data

Вот хотел написать утилиту для импорта большого кол-ва данных в БД (в идеале в разные БД, но для начала PostgreSQL), нужен импорт из текстовых файлов по RegExp именованными полями, где имена будут именами полей в БД, но прежде чем такое делать хотелось бы понять, есть ли уже такое? может и писать ничего не надо.

Comment: У каждой СУБД свои возможности. Во многих уже реализовано нужное вам. Например, в Sql Server [Bulk Import and Export of Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/bulk-import-and-export-of-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Postgers поддерживает импорт из CSV файлов.Ну а так - если очень хочется, то напишите, будет хорошим опытом.

Comment: По хорошему я ищу некое подобие Logstash но с поддержкой реляционок.

Comment: @pnp2000 возможно поможет https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc